# Delete data from listbox first then database

Tags: c#, listbox

I have quiz & question form.
One quiz can container can hold two or more questions,
so the flow will be:

***Quiz Form - select quiz -> question form - CRUID question - Ok/Cancel - Quiz Form***

My problem is when I delete question in question form and I press 'Cancel'. The question still deleted from database because I used this code:

```
Global.deleteData("DELETE FROM Questions WHERE content= '" + var + "'");
Global.questions.RemoveAt(listBoxQuestions.SelectedIndex);
updateListBoxQuestions();
```

What I want is when user click delete button, the program just removes data from the list, so data not deleted yet from the database.

```
Global.questions.RemoveAt(listBoxQuestions.SelectedIndex);
updateListBoxQuestions();
```

When user presses the ok button, the program starts to delete list data removed from database with this code:

```
Global.deleteData("DELETE FROM Questions WHERE content= '" + var + "'");
```

How to do it?

---

my button
[image]

Comment: The easy solution : you can add a hidden field, add the values in the hidden field while removing from select control and delete from db on click of save by retrieving the hidden value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this value in the global

```
List<string> lst_tempValue = new List<string>();
```

in your function

```
Global.questions.RemoveAt(listBoxQuestions.SelectedIndex) ; // removed from the list box.
lst_tempValue.add(listBoxQuestions.SelectedValue); // add into memory.
updateListBoxQuestions(); // do somethings...
```

then when you click on your "ok" button, then you can delete the whole records that you temporary removed.

```
foreach(string s_value in lst_tempValue) // foreach the temporary list
Global.deleteData("DELETE FROM Questions WHERE content= '" + s_value 

 + "'"); // delete what ever stored in the memory
```

Comment: i get error in 'lst_tempValue.add' -> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>.Add(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: and error in this section '(listBoxQuestions.SelectedValue)' ->Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: lst_tempValue.add(listBoxQuestions.SelectedValue.ToString()); // add into memory.

Comment: i get new error 'NullReferenceException was unhandled' in lst_tempValue.Add(listBoxQuestions.SelectedValue.ToString());

Comment: either lst_tempValue is null or listboxquestion is null, or listboxquesetion.selectedvalue is null.

Comment: if lst_tempvalue = null then lst_tempvalue = new List<string>(); what ever is null then you need to make sure you have define a new object on it

Comment: i check it's 'listBoxQuestions.SelectedValue' which give null result...i'm sure i already select data but why it's still give null result?

Comment: is there any places you have listboxquestions.clear() before you enter into selectedvalue?

Comment: maybe you try listboxquestion.SelectedItem.ToString(); instead of selectedvalue.

Answer (score 1):

```
Global.questions.RemoveAt(listBoxQuestions.SelectedIndex);
updateListBoxQuestions();
DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("are you Sure", "question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
if(dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Global.deleteData("DELETE FROM Questions WHERE content= '" + var + "'");

}
```

Comment: but i not use messagebox button, but button like in my post...please check

Comment: what is the value in your listbox? string only ?

Comment: yeah it's string only

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Global.questions` is list of string and user can delete multiple items before pressing **[OK]**, you can try to define another list of string variable to hold tobe deleted questions (variable scope is up to you, as long as it can be accessed in button ok event handler) :

```
Global.deletedQuestions.Add(Global.questions[listBoxQuestions.SelectedIndex]);
Global.questions.RemoveAt(listBoxQuestions.SelectedIndex);
updateListBoxQuestions();
```

then on ok button pressed :

```
var tobeDeleted = "'" + string.Join("','", Global.deletedQuestions) + "'"
Global.deleteData("DELETE FROM Questions WHERE content IN (" + tobeDeleted + ")");
Global.deletedQuestions.Clear();
```

Comment: i don't have var Global.deletedQuestions, it's i create same as Global.deletedData?

Comment: yes, that what I meant by "*define another list of string variable to hold tobe deleted questions*"

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dialog box instead of Ok button on form. As,

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to delete current record", "Delete Record?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    Global.deleteData("DELETE FROM Questions WHERE content IN (" + tobeDeleted + ")");
}
```

Comment: the problem my project need to use ok button not use messagebutton..any idea?

Comment: generate the click event of OK Button. inside that you just write Global.deleteData("DELETE FROM Questions WHERE content IN (" + tobeDeleted + ")");